# How to break out of loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to assign the value of `optiontext` to just one array value at a time.

Is there a way I can break out of the code, because different values are to be assigned to different numbers.

```
for (int i = 1; i <=20; i++) 
    {
        option[i]=optionText;
    }
```

Output:

```
1. Quit
2. Quit
3. Quit
4. Quit
5. Quit
6. Quit
7. Quit
8. Quit
9. Quit
10. Quit
11. Quit
12. Quit
13. Quit
14. Quit
15. Quit
16. Quit
17. Quit
18. Quit
19. Quit
20. Quit
```

I just want quit for number one, not the whole 20 options and should only display the numbers that have values.

what it should look like

```
     1. Quit
     2. Get information
     3. Display n integers, first descending then ascending
     4. Display n squares with odds descending, evens ascending
     5. Check if one string is the reverse of another
```

Comment: Then why are you assigning it twenty times? What do you expect in 2-20?

Comment: do you understand `your` code ?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch another optionText

Comment: @Matthew its a string array

Comment: @MrSimpleMind I understand its assigning it twenty times but i need to assign the optionText value to just pne number each because each optionText value for each number is different

Comment: "Is there a way I can break the code" < Lol

Comment: Either you haven't put up your question clearly or you are lost somewhere in code .. You are assigning same `optionText` variable to all index positions of array so o/p you are getting is expected .. If you say that `optionText` is different each time then clearly it is not happening and you need to look into other part of your code which you have not posted ..

Answer (score 2):

If you want to assign a value to just one array element then there is no need to use the loop. E.g. if you want to assign  `optionText` to first element then you can simply do:

```
option[0] = optionText;
```

Answer (score 0):

The i in `option[i]` specifies which array index you want. If you just want quit for the first option in the array, you do not need a for loop.

For example you should use, 
`option[0] = optionText;` 
hence, the first element is 0.

Answer (score 0):

In this situation you does not need the for,, just create an integer pointer to fill the array.. something like this.

```
private int pointer =0;  // define it as an attribute (global variable)

protected void buton_click(){
    option[pointer]=optionText;
    pointer++;  // to be ready for the next index
}
```